# Why TextView breaks line when width of line is equal to width of TextView

Tags: android, text, textview

I have a `TextView` which its `textSize` is `3`. I want to display this String in that:

```
String line = 
لورم  ایپسوم  متن  ساختگی  با  تولید  سادگی  نامفهوم  از  صنعت  چاپ و با استفاده از طراحان گرافیک است. چاپگرها و متون بلکه روزنامه و مجله در ستون و سطرآنچنان که لازم است و برای شرایط فعلی تکنولوژی مورد نیاز و کاربردهای متنوع با هدف بهبود;
```

I calculate available width of `TextView` for text at run time by implementing  `ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener` interface:

```
int textAreaWidth;
@Override
public void onGlobalLayout() {
    textAreaWidth = textView.getWidth() - (textView.getPaddingLeft() + textView.getPaddingRight());
}
```

Also I calculate width of `line` like this:

```
TextPaint textPaint = textView.getPaint();
float lineWidth = textPaint.measureText(line);
```

In `Logcat` I can see values of `textAreaWidth` and `lineWidth`:

```
textAreaWidth > 668
lineWidth > 668.0
```

As you can see `textAreaWidth` and `lineWidth` are equal, but `TextView` breaks `line` into **2** lines and display them:

```
لورم  ایپسوم  متن  ساختگی  با  تولید  سادگی  نامفهوم  از  صنعت  چاپ و با استفاده از طراحان گرافیک است. چاپگرها و متون بلکه روزنامه و مجله در ستون و سطرآنچنان که لازم است و برای شرایط فعلی تکنولوژی مورد نیاز و کاربردهای متنوع با هدف 
بهبود
```

Why `TextView` breaks `line` while width of line is equal to available width for text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm adding this as an answer instead of a comment because it is relatively in-depth, but unfortunately I don't have a precise answer to your question.

I have generally used two different methods to measure text:

- `TextPaint.measureText()`
- `TextPaint.getTextBounds()`

In my personal experience, the first one does a better job at giving you an accurate measure of the width of the text, and the second one does a better job at giving you an accurate measure of the height of the text.

However, neither method gives a perfect measure of the precise size needed for the text (i.e., the smallest bounding box the text fits in) *and* neither method gives the same answer as what `TextView` uses.

My (admittedly limited) understanding is that `TextView` uses the `StaticLayout` and `DynamicLayout` classes for measuring text. Having very briefly looked into those classes, I don't see an obvious way to answer "how wide will this text be"; instead they seem to be better at answering "how many lines will this text be, given N pixels of width".

Hope this helps point you in the right direction.

Comment: Thank you. You cleared the subject. But what about `textPaint.breakText`? I used this: `int countedChars = textPaint.breakText(line, 0, line.length(), true, textAreaWidth, measuredWidth);` and then `Log.i("justification", "not countedChars: " + (line.length() - countedChars) + " (\"" + line.substring(countedChars) + "\")");
        Log.i("justification", "measuredWidth: " + measuredWidth[0]);`
Output is:
`not countedChars: 1 ("د")`
`measuredWidth: 668.0`
It seems this method can understand that whole of `line` is long for `TextView`. Am I right?

Comment: I don't have any experience with `breakText`, sorry. If it works for you, what you've posted seems reasonable to me.

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to be single line, then use maxlines property of TextView :

```
android: maxLines="1"
```